# temp file is not removed when created using File::Temp module

Tags: perl

The `File::Temp` module is not deleting the file on exit.

I create a temp file and pass that file to other functions in which the file is opened for reading and writing.

Here is the code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use strict ;  
use warnings ;  
use Data::Dumper;   
use File::Temp qw/ tempfile tempdir /;  
use sigtrap qw(die normal-signals error-signals);  

sub temp{  
    my $decrypted_file_path = "/home/programming/perl";  
    my $file = new File::Temp(DIR => $decrypted_file_path, SUFFIX => '.tmp',UNLINK=>1)->filename;  
    print Dumper $file;  
    writeFile($file);  
    my @arr = parse($file);  
    return ;  
}  

sub writeFile{  
   my ($file) = @_ ;  
   print $file ;  
   open(my $fh,'>', $file) or die "cannot open : $!";  
   print $fh 'this is test' ;  
   close $fh ;    
}  

sub parse{  
    my ($file) = @_ ;  
    open(my $fh,'<', $file) or die "cannot open : $!";  
    my @arr = <$fh> ;  
    close $fh ;  
    return @arr ;  
}  

temp();
```

The problem is when the program terminates, the files are still present. How can I automatically remove the files?

Perl version: v5.10.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using [File::Temp](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Temp) the wrong way.
It will already give you an object which contains the filehandle and filename.
If you do

```
my $filename = new File::Temp(...)->filename;
```

then the object returned by File::Temp containing the filehandle will be destroyed immediately. It's similar to:

```
my $file = new File::Temp(...);
my $filename = $file->filename;
undef $file;
```

So it creates a file and directly deletes it, and all you are left with is the filename. Then you open this file yourself and never take care of deleting it.

Use it like that:

```
my $temp = File::Temp->new(...);
# is already a filehandle
print $temp $content;
# explicitly remove it, otherwise it will be removed when it falls out of scope
undef $temp;
```

Comment: Great explanation man. Thanks!!!   
One more concern, will it automatically delete the temp files, if the use ctrl+c to interrupt the program?

Comment: Oops. sorry about that. I have another issue with this approach, i have some command written in the temp file, after making the temp file executable, when I try to execute the command :  
   system("$temp_file") ;
it says 'Text file busy '

Answer (score 2):

I observe the same behavior on version 5.16.3.  Using `new` and `filename` on the same line looks odd to me.  If I separate the two functions, the file is automatically removed:

```
my $tmp = File::Temp->new(DIR => $decrypted_file_path, SUFFIX => '.tmp', UNLINK => 1);
my $file = $tmp->filename();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the option `CLEANUP => 1`.
See more in the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Temp.html).

Comment: Read the documentation. Create just a temp directory and use `CLEANUP=>1`. Then create the file(s) you need in this temp directory. The directory with all its content will be removed automatically when your program exits.